# PhpStorm live template variable wrap/surround

Tags: drupal, phpstorm, code-snippets, live-templates

I have a Sublime Text snippet I would like to convert to a PhpStorm's Live Template. Currently I am stuck with the possibility to wrap already defined variables.

e.g.

```
${2:${1:HOOK}}_mail
```

A first `tab` in sublime text would output the following.

```
MY_HOOK_mail
```

A second `tab` would then allow me to overwrite the MY_HOOK

```
MY_OVERWRITE_mail
```

Would this be possible with live templates?

As reference the sublime text snippet I am trying to convert: https://github.com/iampuma/d7ssnippets/blob/master/hook_mail.sublime-snippet

- Reference how this actually works in Sublime Text (line 8):
  [image]

**SOLUTION**:
 - Thanks to @LazyOne.

Live template:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function $MODULE_NAME$_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch($key) {
    case '$MODULE_NAME1$_mail':
      $message['subject'] = $SUBJECT$;
      $message['body'][] = '$BODY$';
  }
}
```

Variables:
[image]

Comment: I have not worked with Sublime so do not know how exactly it should work in this case (maybe you can record some animation/screencats?). But with Live Templates you can use 2 variables: 1 for each part, something like `$MY$_$HOOK$_mail` where you can provide default values for each of them and overwrite it independently. I'm not sure at all that you can have multi-level/nested variables.

Comment: I have updated my question with how this would look like in Sublime Text. See Line 8.

Comment: Nested variables no -- you have to use multiple variables where you can assign default values or value of another variable (and then overwrite when typing as needed) -- e.g. `$NAME1$ (used as function name) and `$NAME2$` used in `case`.

Comment: If you have issues -- post your Live Template (template as text + your variables (screenshot)).

Comment: @LazyOne thanks! I could indeed just use the default value of a previous defined variable. Did not think about that!

Comment: Better post your updates as proper answer -- will help other users in similar situation (not everyone read whole question properly and can easily skip your solution; plus, questions without proper answers have lower visibility and may not even be shown in search results/considered as good result)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, done.

Comment: Great. Now -- do not forget to accept it to further improve its visibility :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: - Thanks to @LazyOne.

The trick is just to use the previous variable as default value. E.g:

Live template:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function $MODULE_NAME$_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch($key) {
    case '$MODULE_NAME1$_mail':
      $message['subject'] = $SUBJECT$;
      $message['body'][] = '$BODY$';
  }
}
```

Variables:
[image]